# NTP symmetric mode

Tags: ntpd, ntp

I'm configuring NTP symmetric modes.
Say I have Peer A (192.168.101.1) and Peer B(192.168.101.2) and configure their `ntp.conf` as follows:

```
# Peer A
peer 192.168.101.2
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

For Peer B, I set both its `server` and `peer` to A.

```
# Peer B
peer 192.168.101.1
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14
```

If I set their time apart (like 10 minutes), they each will synchronize locally instead of with each other(may I should've waited longer).

And I have to add A as B's server in B's `ntp.conf`:

```
# Peer B
peer 192.168.101.1
server 192.168.101.1
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14
```

Then B will synchronize its time to A quickly.

This leaves me in doubt about the symmetric mode's effectiveness. 
Why not just set A as B's server and both of them as clients' servers? If A is down, the cluster time can still fail over to B and stay in synchronism.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @dfc sorry, my question is not well formed and I've forgot what my problem was then. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what problem you are trying to solve. It looks like you want to provide time to local clients and have some fault tolerance. You should use the [orphan mode](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/orphan.html) this is why it was added in 4.2.2. Does this diagram look like what you are interested in doing:

[image]

Why are you using the undisciplined local clock?